# uploading a folder with a sub folder doesn't work after updating chrome 33

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, file-upload, upload

```
<form action="a.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple="" directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

http://www.w3bees.com/2013/03/directory-upload-using-html-5-and-php.html

The above method worked on uploading a folder with one or more sub folders before the recent update of chrome. However, chrome now shows "This webpage is not available,  The webpage at ....a.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. Error code: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED" if I upload a folder that contains a subfolder. It works fine if the selected folder contains no subfolder.

Does anyone get an idea on it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue. The problem is that browser tries to access to the subfolder itself. Therefore you have to use some "pre upload" function to exclude them from the sending data and upload files manually with XMLHttpRequest.

This is possible solution. You need to add this `<script>` tag inside `<head>` tag of index.php file from your example.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('submit_button').onclick = function(e) {
        var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
        uploadFiles(files);
        return false;
    }
}


function uploadFiles(files){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = new FormData();

    // go through files
    for (var i in files){
        if( files[i].webkitRelativePath && files[i].type){
            data.append(i, files[i]);
        }
    };

    xhr.open('POST', "index.php", true);
    xhr.send(data);

}
</script>
```

also need to add `id="submit_button"` to the submit button. And of course you have to change your php code to handle new data correctly.

Comment: What if we want to upload recursively?

Comment: What do you mean? Several directories or several requests? Or something different?